# How to only concatenate changes in gruntjs?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-concat

I'm new to **grunt**, I used [grunt-contrib-concat](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat) to concatenate my several CSS files into one file. The problem is every time I issue `grunt concat`, it appends everything again and again even if I did not change anything.

example -

file1.css

```
div {
    color:#ffffff;
}
```

file2.css

```
body {
    color: green;
}
```

When I issue `grunt concat` for the first time:

```
body {
  color: green; }

div {
  color: #ffffff; }
```

When I issue `grunt concat` for the second time:

```
body {
  color: green; }

div {
  color: #ffffff; }

body {
  color: green; }

div {
  color: #ffffff; }
```

I know it is the default behavior of **grunt concat**, but what I want to know is:

*Is there a way to change this behavior in **grunt concat**  or can I use any other grunt plugins which will only concatenate things that are not in the destination file?*

NOTE: I searched the internet but I found it a little difficult to get the solution I need. It would be appreciated if you could share a link which might be useful to me.

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like your output file is in the same folder as the source files

Comment: yes @leemo, is that a problem

Comment: yes because everytime you run the task it will also concat the existing output file once before overwriting itself

Comment: yes if i changed the directory it worked. thanks.